# Need to count a row in a column based on the logged in username

Tags: php, mysql, sql, count

I need to count from a column in my database based on a row equal to the username logged in

```
$this->setParams('username', $users->getInfo($_SESSION['user']['id'], 'username'));
```

I need it to count how many times a username is repeated in that table.

```
<?php echo number_format(mysql_num_rows(mysql_query("SELECT from login_logs WHERE username = '".$_SESSION['user']['id'] ."username"))); ?>
```

It coming up as 0 even though I see 4 values in the database.

How can I get the correct count?

Comment: what does the data looks like? also, why are you appending `username` after the actual username? are you saving all usernames suffixed with `username`? Also, you need to declare what you want to select. you should look at your error logs.

Comment: If I use {username} it states the current logged in users username. I'm trying to count from a table how many time the users name is there from login_logs to count how many invalid logins there have been.

Comment: `WHERE username = '".$_SESSION['user']['id'] ."username"` i am referring to this part. Why are you appending "username" at the end of `$_SESSION['user']['id']`? if I had a username on your site, would you save it as `khudermusername` instead of just `khuderm`?

Comment: I no idea..I actually just got into PHP and I've been reading for hours and hours on how to count data from a row and every code I've attempted using mysql_query has not worked.

Comment: so it doesn't work huh?

Comment: It just gives the value 0.

Comment: I think I might just use if($_SESSION['user']['id']){ and just echo the data value using count.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First off, like everyone who sees `mysql_query` says, use PDO. However, for the purposes of learning, `mysql_query` is just fine but totally unacceptable on a production server. Mainly because `mysql_query` is very insecure. It is prone to stuff like sql injections that can really mess up the server or even give access to hackers. Once you get comfortable using PHP and MySQL, read up on sql injection and securing your code.

Back to the real question, you are not seeing anything because your select query is all out of whack.
Let's break it down. I only indented your query so we can talk about it in detail.

```
SELECT 
from login_logs 
WHERE username = '".$_SESSION['user']['id'] ."username"
```

There are couple issues with this query.

1. You are not defining what you want to select. `SELECT *` will return every column. However, if you are just counting and don't care about retrieving the data, you can use an indexed column like the id field `SELECT id`. This improves performance. Perhaps something you want to read later on.
2. Your where condition is pretty much rendered useless by appending `"username"` to it. Let's say that I am the logged in user. My username is `khuderm` so `$_SESSION['user']['id']` would return `khuderm`. So if you substitute the variable with my username, it become `WHERE username = 'khudermusername` when it should just be looking for `khuderm`. So removing that will fix the problem partially. Also, you are missing a closing quote surrounding the username value. So instead of appending the literal word `"username"` to the actual logged in user's username, you should be appending `"'"` to close out that quote in the beginning `WHERE username = '"`

If you can follow these steps, you should be able to fix your problem. An easy way to debug MySQL queries in PHP is to echo it to get the final query with variables and such filled in. So anywhere in your code, echoing `"SELECT from login_logs WHERE username = '".$_SESSION['user']['id'] ."username"` would show you exactly what is sent to the db for querying. Once you have that, run the result of the echo in phpmyadmin or workbench or whatever you are using to look at the db and it should tell you what is wrong with the query.

Don't forget to read up on sql injections, PDO, and prepared statements. Hope this was insightful and happy coding!

Comment: I can use workbench to test this? Is there a tutorial on how?

Comment: copy the resulting query from the echo and run it in workbench

Comment: <?php echo number_format(mysql_num_rows(mysql_query("SELECT * from cms_login_logs WHERE username = '".$_SESSION['user']['id'] ."'"))); ?> Is the last thing I came up from what you told me. I think it may be a syntax number because I'm trying to count.

Comment: just echo `"SELECT * from cms_login_logs WHERE username = '".$_SESSION['user']['id'] ."'"` this part. no need to run it through those functions. then test the resulting query in workbench see if that works. if that query returns a result then something else is wrong.

Answer (score 0):

You are looking for `SELECT COUNT(username) FROM logins_logs WHERE username = "your username"`

But you should use `PDO` and prepare your query instead of `mysql_query`.

Example :

```
$options = array(
    PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE               => PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION,
    PDO::ATTR_DEFAULT_FETCH_MODE    => PDO::FETCH_ASSOC,
    PDO::MYSQL_ATTR_INIT_COMMAND    => 'SET NAMES \'UTF8\'',
);
$dsn= 'mysql:host=your_host;dbname=your_db';
$pdo = new PDO($dsn, 'root', 'root_password', $options);

$stmt = $pdo->prepare('SELECT COUNT(username) FROM logins_logs WHERE username = :username');
$stmt->bindParam(':username', $users->getInfo($_SESSION['user']['id'], 'username'));
$stmt->execute();
$result = $stmt->fetch();
echo $result['COUNT(username)'];
```

Comment: So I need to create a PDO connection to count one row out of the database?

Comment: Yes, anyway some kind of connection, even if you don't want to use PDO

Comment: You could also go with `mysqli_query`

Comment: I just tried that and it messed up the entire page.

Comment: How could I use mysqli_query. I just need to count those tables based on that users username.